# Is there an equivalent of pg_backend_pid in Cassandra?

Tags: postgresql, cassandra, database-trigger

I am starting to use Cassandra and I need to work with several sessions without creating different roles. I am trying to implement a record that saves the **session ID** in each modification (aka AuditLog). Previously it was already implemented in Postgresql, so I learned about triggers. I am adapting to Cassandra's triggers. So far I can't find a way to track a cql session / connection that doesn't include an external process. But in this way the use of triggers is excluded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cassandra has the function to enable or disable traces with the command [TRACING](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/cql/cql/cql_reference/cqlsh_commands/cqlshTracing.html), which will create traces for all the queries in that session. There is also a more useful approach with [`nodetool settraceprobability`](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/tools/nodetool/settraceprobability.html), where you can determine a percentage of traces stored.

All those traces are kept in a separate keyspace, for 3.x this is `system_traces`, the traces are kept with a Time to Live (TTL) of 24 hours.